# How to create transparent images in Java ME

Tags: image, java-me, transparent

How can I create an editable but transparent image in Java ME?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create the transparent image programmatically then following is the snippet.

```
int width = 50, height = 50;
Image  image = Image.createImage(width,height); 

int[] rgbArr = new int[width * height];

image.getRGB(rgbArr, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

for (int i = 0; i < rgbArr.length; i++) {

   if(rgbArr[i] == 0xFFFFFFFF){

       rgbArr[i] = 0x00000000;

   }

}

Image transImage = Image.createRGBImage(rgbArr, width, height, true);
```

Now you can get the graphics object on the transImage and paint whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use a GIF or PNG - both support transparent pixels.